# return string instead of model

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using spring 3.2 and I have come with one requirement and can't figure out how to achieve it, first please look for below

1. We mostly use model in Spring MVC which is use for data binding
2. @ResponseBody annotation returns the string as http response

So my requirement is I want to use both together in single method base on condition, Here is my code

```
@RequestMapping(value="userAddEditSubmit.htm", method={RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String userAddEditSubmit(
        @ModelAttribute("user") User user,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HttpSession session,
        Model model
    ) throws Exception {
        try {
            //Here is my logic

            return "redirect:" + url;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

So above is my method which returns specific jsp with model attribute, **but now in one condition I have requirement to return String data instead of whole jsp** in the same method, what can I do to achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply return `null` from that method when your condition is met and write to the response yourself. Spring assumes that when a method returns `null` it has handled the response itself.

Comment: Okay got something and can you say how to write response? by adding model attribute or PrintWriter class or something other?

Comment: Just ask Spring to inject a HttpServletResponse instance into your controller method by declaring it as a argument. You can use *getWriter* or *getOutputStream* to write to it. [Also read the warning in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getOutputStream())

Comment: Ok I try and get back to you.

Comment: Hi I had try to return with null it is throwing 404 error. No use

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. Please update your question with  your current code. Also try to log org.springframework at DEBUG level and share the log output of the one single request.